# Find similar fragments in several text files

Tags: programming, text-processing, text-search

Given several text (in fact, Perl source) files I want to find long fragments which are repeated in more than one file.

There preferably should be an option to ignore amount of white space and/or indenting.

It would be event better, if the software can find not only exact repetitions but just similar text fragments (with little differences).

Any Linux software for this?

Comment: I would try these: http://askubuntu.com/questions/651166/best-alternative-for-winmerge#661055

Comment: @onurcano22 They seem to do a different thing than I asked. They just compare two files (or two directories).